# Conditional probability of random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-probability

Say I have random variables ~$Exp$ and lets call them $X$ with rate $\lambda$ and $Y$ with rate $\mu$. How do I find $\mathbb{P}\{X>Y|Y>4\}$? I know that $\mathbb{P}\{X>Y\} = \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda}$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Can you compute $P(X\gt Y\gt4)$? If not, why?

Comment: Ah so this would be the probability that $X>Y$ and $Y>4$ (hence I could use the law of conditional probability to find the answer). However I'm not sure how to compute $\mathbb{P}\{X>Y>4\}$.

Comment: OK, you are "not sure". My question was WHY you are not sure. Did you write down the distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Yup, so that would be $\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu x} $ since they are independent.

Comment: Rather $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}\mu e^{-\mu y}\mathbf 1_{y\gt0}$. Now, how to deduce $P(X\gt Y\gt 4)$ from this density?

Comment: Integrate $y$ from $4$ to infinity and $x$ from $y$ to infinity?

Comment: Right. And the result would be?

Comment: I'm getting $e^{-(\lambda y + 4 \mu)}$...I don't think that's correct, though.

Comment: The double integral should yield a number, not a function of $y$. Please show your work in details (as usual...).

Comment: $$\int_y^{\infty} \int_4^{\infty} \lambda e^{- \lambda x}  \mu e^{-\mu y} dy dx$$ $$ = \int_y^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x - 4\mu} dx$$ $$=e^{-(\lambda y + 4 \mu)}$$

Comment: No, you cannot integrate from $y$ to $\infty$ once the integral over $y$ is performed. Just try the other order...

Comment: Ok, I know get $$\frac{\mu e^{-4(\mu + \lambda)}}{\mu + \lambda}$$

Comment: If that is correct, then dividing by $P (Y > 4)$ gives me the following identity: $$P(X>Y|Y>4) = P(X>Y)P(X>4)$$

Comment: And so what? But, say, what did you find for $P(X\gt Y\mid Y\gt4)$ exactly?

Comment: $$\frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda}e^{-4\lambda}$$

Comment: That is correct. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no answer till now let me write it down.

$F(x) = \begin{cases} \lambda e^{- \lambda x} & \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x < 0$} \end{cases}$.

$F(y) = \begin{cases} \mu e^{- \mu y} & \text{if $y \ge 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $y < 0$} \end{cases}$.

Now $X$ and $Y$ are independent and so the joint probability will be

$F(x, y) = \begin{cases} \lambda \mu e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\mu x} & \text{if $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$} \\ 0 & \text{Otherwies} \end{cases}$.

$P(X > Y | Y > 4) = \frac{P(X > Y , Y > 4)}{P(Y > 4)}$

You can easily find out the value of $P(Y > 4)$ by integrating $F(Y = y)$ in $(4,\infty)$. The value will be $e^{-4 \mu}$. Please verify.

To find the value of $P(X > Y | Y > 4)$ integrate the joint probability function for $X > Y$ and $Y > 4$ (Double Integration). You shall get $\frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}e^{-4(\lambda + \mu)}$. Please check.

Hope it is done. Answer will be $\frac{\mu e^{-4\lambda}}{\lambda + \mu}$

Comment: Well adapted to prevent the OP to understand themselves the proof, which they were slowly arriving at in the comments. About your post: neither F(X=x), F(Y=y), F(X=x,Y=y) have any meaning that I know of.

Comment: Sorry I was also solving this question. So I posted it.

Comment: And now we are left with the unconventional notations F(X=x), F(Y=y), F(X=x,Y=y). What are these?

Comment: $F(X = x)$ is the probability density function with random variable $X$ which takes values $x$. Similarly $F(Y= y)$ and $F(X = x, Y = y)$

Comment: These have the huge drawback of suggesting that P(X=x), say, is of interest. Please use more conventional notations.

Comment: Is $F_X(x)$ suits batter? Please let me know about these drawbacks.

Comment: Here is a crazy suggestion: have a look at some reference... // "Please let me know about these drawbacks." I just did.

Comment: I shall look other foreign books. The books I use to study probability and statistics use this notation.

Comment: Please indicate some books using F(X=x) to denote the value of the density of X at x.

Comment: Fundamentals of Mathematical Statistics Gupta, Kapur.

Comment: No access. Note that F is universally used to denote the CDF and that the event [X=x] has probability 0 for every continuous random variable X. Two reasons to avoid F(X=x).

Comment: Thank you sir. I shall edit the answer.

Comment: By the way, what would be a section of the book by Gupta and Kapur where they use the notation F(X=x)?

Comment: Would they NOT be using this notation, by any chance? (By the way, using F to denote some PDF is ALSO a bad idea.)